# add badgeview in actionbar tabs

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I've been googling but failed enough.

this is the code snippet and result to what i currently have.

[image]

```
        LinearLayout mLinear = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) mLinear.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);

    //mTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.))
    mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    mTextView.setText("Update");

    BadgeView mBadgeView = new BadgeView(this , mTextView);
    mBadgeView.setText("2");
    mBadgeView.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
    mBadgeView.show();

    Tab updates = mActionBar.newTab();
    updates.setCustomView(null);
    updates.setCustomView(mLinear);
    updates.setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(updates);
```

heres what i really want.
[image]

is this possible for actionbarsherlock tabs?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: nope sorry. if you found a solution post a link here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `LayoutParams` of your LinearLayout to `MATCH_PARENT` to make your custom view take up all the available space in the tab.

I wrote a blog post on the topic of adding a badge to a tab: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/06/24/adding-a-badge-to-an-actionbar-tab